# android DDMS logcat filter by name

Tags: android, filter, logcat, ddms

Is there any way to setup a logcat filter by name?  I realize they have the filter by log tag, but my app may have various different tags.  I can use the filter by pid, but of course everytime i recompile and redeploy this pid changes.  I'd like to be able to fitler it by com.mycompany.appname or something along those lines.  is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by adding a prefix to my log tags. For ejample:

- NameOfMyApp-Home
- NameOfMyApp-Settings

and then I use `grep` with:

```
adb shell logcat | grep NameOfMyApp
```

Comment: is this possible in eclipse, too?

Comment: I guess you can do it from eclipse. There is a search edit text over the bottom of the logcat screen.

Comment: wow, thank you, i haven´t already seen it :) but this one just looks up the log´s content, not the log´s tag :(